# Can not open .tif image

Tags: python, type-conversion, tiff

I want to open a .tif image but I always get error for every library I tried to use.
I tried with PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('filepath/img_name.tif')
```

but I get the following error:

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'filepath/img_name.tif'

(This error does not mean that I can not find the file so the directory should be good)

I tried with tifffile:

```
import tifffile
img = tifffile.imread('filepath/img_name.tif')
```

I got the following error:

NotImplementedError: unpacking 14-bit integers to uint16 not supported.

I am pretty sure the problem is that the picture because I tried to open a tif image on the internet and it work just by doing this: [this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0TmK.png)

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('a_image.tif')
```

Is there a way to convert my 14-bit picture to a 16-bit picture?
(I know that I could multiply by 4 to get to 16-bit but I do not know how)

Comment: Tifffile can unpack 14-bit integers if the [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) package is installed.

Comment: Please upload the actual .tif file and provide a link to it so it will be available to folks trying to help (the link currently in your question is to a .png image).

Comment: Actually cgohlke resolved the problem. I needed to install imagedecodecs and it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed imagedecodecs and tifffile has been able to open it

```
import tifffile
img = tifffile.imread(tif_name)
```

The problem was that my image was in 14bits.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your TIF file has more than one frame. That could be a problem. Try:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("animation.tif")
image.seek(1) # skip to the second frame

try:
    while 1:
        image.seek(image.tell()+1)
        # do something to im
except EOFError:
    pass # end of sequence
```

From the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/tutorial.html#reading-sequences).